# Webpack & typescript: watch not working for exported intefaces

Tags: typescript, webpack

UPD.

I have two folders frontend and shared that get bundled by webpack using ts-loader.

Problem is that change of exported **interfaces** from shared folder don't get detected.

If i add in IThemes.ts export like

```
export const x = 2
```

than changes are detected again even for interface change.

example of exported IThemes.ts:

```
export interface IGeneralTheme {
  isDay: boolean
  day: ITheme
  night: ITheme
}
```

example of interface use ThemeContext.tsx:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { deepClone, ITheme, IGeneralTheme } from '@shared'
import { ThemeProvider, createGlobalStyle } from 'styled-components'

type ThemeContextProps = {
  theme: ITheme
  generalTheme: IGeneralTheme
  isDay: boolean
  setGeneralTheme: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<IGeneralTheme>>
}

export const ThemeContext = React.createContext<Partial<ThemeContextProps>>({})
```

---

tsconfig.base.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "strictBindCallApply": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "strictFunctionTypes": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "../../node_modules"
  ]
}
```

tsconfig.json in frontend folder:

```
{
  "extends": "../configs/tsconfig.base.json",
  "include": [
    "**/*",
    "../shared/**/*"
  ],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@shared": [
        "../shared/index"
      ],
      "@frontend": [
        "index"
      ]
    },
    "jsx": "react",
    "target": "es2015"
  }
}
```

webpack.base.js:

```
const path = require('path')
const webpack = require('webpack')

module.exports = {
  entry: '../frontend/client.tsx',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve('../../public'),
    filename: 'react_bundle.js'
  },
  devtool: 'source-map',
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.json', '.ts', '.tsx'],
    alias: {
      '@frontend': path.resolve(__dirname, '../frontend/index'),
      '@shared': path.resolve(__dirname, '../shared/index')
    }
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.ts(x?)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'ts-loader'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
      },
      {
        enforce: 'pre',
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'source-map-loader'
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(/moment[\/\\]locale$/, /ru/)]
}
```

webpack.dev.js:

```
const merge = require('webpack-merge')
const base = require('./webpack.base.js')
const webpack = require('webpack')

module.exports = merge(base, {
  mode: 'development',
  watch: true,
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      isProd: false
    })
  ]
})
```

Runned by command from configs folder: npx webpack --config webpack.dev.js

Comment: Does this answer your question? [webpack-dev-server & ts-loader not reloads when interface changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53312320/webpack-dev-server-ts-loader-not-reloads-when-interface-changed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to enable TS compiler option `importsNotUsedAsValues`, see: https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader/issues/1138

Answer (score 6):

Found answer to my own question after i saw that it's [not working only for interface:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53312320/webpack-dev-server-ts-loader-not-reloads-when-interface-changed)

> I encountered a similar issue. What solved it for me was to change the
>   filenames of files that contain only interfaces from *.ts to *.d.ts.
>
> Apparently, the ts-loader generates output only for files that give
>   JavaScript output, and typescript definition files. The output is then
>   read by the webpack watcher, and webpack updates if one of these files
>   changes.
>
> In your case, you have files that generate no JavaScript output and
>   are not typescript definition files. So no output will be generated
>   from them, and the webpack watcher won't notice when they change.

Alternative is awesome-typescript-loader that seems work fine.

Comment: thanks for finding that post. I've spent the better part of two days scouring the internets and found some disturbing things along the way for this issue. Granted I thought it was a laravel-mix issue. Not until this morning did I realise it only happened in watch mode therefore a webpack issue. Once again thanks man.